# How to prove that $[G:xHx^{-1}] = [G:H]$ given $H \le G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The problem is as follows:

> Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$ (i.e., $H \le G$); let $x$ be any element of $G$ (i.e., $x \in G$). To prove that $[G:xHx^{-1}] = [G:H]$.

I am able to justify that the $xHx^{-1}$ is indeed a subgroup of $G$ (i.e., $xHx^{-1} \le G$) and that $|xHx^{-1}| = |H|$.

To prove that $[G:xHx^{-1}] = [G:H]$, it is necessary to provide a bijective function $F$ between the set of (different, left) cosets of $H$ (denoted $S = \{ aH : a \in G \}$) and that of $xHx^{-1}$ (denoted $T = \{ a (xHx^{-1}) : a \in G\} $).

I have tried the function $F(aH) = a(xHx^{-1})$, but failed to show it is bijective. Could someone offer a hint of the feasible function?

Comment: That $F$ is not a well-defined function.

Comment: Since conjugation by $x$ is an automorphism of $G$, the obvious correspondece is left coset rep. $a$ of $H$ corresponds to rep. $xax^{-1}$ of $xHx^{-1}$, although $a \mapsto ax^{-1}$ will also work.

Comment: @Woria Do you mean that $F(aH) = a(xHx^{-1})$ is *not* a function at all?

Comment: @hengxin, Yes that's what I mean, otherwise since for every $h\in H$ we have $eH=hH$ so $F(eH)=F(hH)$ and so $xHx^{-1}=h(xHx^{-1})$, thus $h\in xHx^{-1}$, i.e. $H\subseteq xHx^{-1}$, that is not necessarily true.

Comment: @Woria Thanks. I have never thought about it. I am trying to "make up" a bijective function but forget to check whether it is a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the map $aH \mapsto x(aH)x^{-1}$. Note that $x(aH)x^{-1} = (xax^{-1})xHx^{-1}$.

More generally, if $\phi$ is an automorphism of $G$ and $H \leq G$, then $[G:H] = [G : \phi(H)]$ since $aH \mapsto \phi(aH)$ is a bijection between left cosets of $H$ and $\phi(H)$. Your problem is the case where $\phi(g) = xgx^{-1}$.

Comment: I'm new on abstract algebra, I can prove the mapping is a bijection, but why $|\left\{axHx^{−1}:a\in G\right\}|=|\left\{xax^{-1}xHx^{−1}:a\in G\right\}|$? LHS$\geq$RHS is obvious, but G may be an infinite group. Could you explain to me in detail?