# Finding a normal subgroup of finite index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and $H\le G$ with $(G:H)<\infty$. Then, there is a subgroup $N$ of $H$ such  that $N\unlhd G$ and $(G:N)<\infty$.

I have constructed such $N$:
$$ N=\bigcap_{i=1}^m\ g_i H g_i^{-1}, $$
where $G=\bigcup_{i=1}^m g_i N_G(H)$ ($m$ conjugacy classes of $H$), and showed $N$ is normal.

What remains to prove is $(G:gHg^{-1})=(G:H)$, so that 
$$ (G:N)\le\prod_{i=1}^m\ (G:H)<\infty. $$
How can I prove that?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700117/how-to-prove-that-gxhx-1-gh-given-h-le-g/